# Default activity not found in my android studio

Tags: android

I have created a new project in android studio and when i am trying to run it ,it is saying default activity not found.i have checked my manifest file this does not contain any problem.
there is a Red X Mark android studio application while running

Comment: What is your android studio version??

Comment: paste stacktrace and manifest

Comment: android studio 3.2.1

Comment: go to your Edit Configuration and take a screenshot of that, maybe there's something off about your Launch Options.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I would try to rebuild the Projekt.
Please coment the output of the Logcat.

Answer (score 16):

**Exit** Android Studio.

**Go to** path > `C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOW_USER_NAME\.AndroidStudio3.3\system`

**Remove** `/caches` folder.

Make sure

- you have **defined Launcher activity in Manifest file** for
  one Activity
- you have **set the default activity from Configurations**
- you have **set the selected activity from Configurations.**

Comment: works perfectly. + i removed other caches folder or temp folder too.

Comment: Yes; Restarting android studio by selecting "Invalidate catches and Restart" from file menu works sometimes.

Comment: Perfect answer <3

Comment: "Invalidate caches and Restart" didn't work. This did!

Comment: This is the one that works for me after upgrading to ver. 4. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I have found my way around this by adding the build configuration manually, and it's working for me:

1. Select Edit Configurations from the drop-down next to the run button.
2. Under `Android App` on the left select `app` option, this will show the app configuration settings on the right
3. Under the `Launch Options` section there is a `Launch` dropdown select the `Specified Activity` option.
4. Another field "Activity" will appear to select your default activity(Select the default one in your manifest).
5. Click OK and sync the project with gradle files and it should work.

Comment: i have follwed these steps but that does not work .i have got solution of my problem that i uninstall android studio and reinstall it now it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

two Method for solving this problem

Method 1.make sure that default activity is define in your manifest

Method 2. even default activity is define but not solved than go to your manifest file click on merged Manifest at bottom left side of your manifest file and you will see the side drawer menu of your manifest file you will see the error and from there you can solved your error by click on suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manifest file and under the activity tags make sure it has:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_name Here"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Make sure that the line containing the action `android:name= "android.intent.action.MAIN"`
is included in the activity tag of the application.

Also make sure that activity name is corresponding to the android:name of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this code..

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: check main activity set layout

Comment: also restart again android studio

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your Launcher activity intent filter has this

```
tools:node="remove"
```

If yes, remove it and error will be resolved. This piece of code will be used when we are having flavors in our project structure, in-order to remove a Launcher activity.

Else, Two launcher icons will be installed.

Comment: Can you please be specific about where it would be found?

Comment: Check in your Android Manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

i have resolved this issue by changing the location of android studio from program files to program filesx86